# Issues regarding NetBeans and JDK 10.0.2

Tags: java, netbeans, java-10

How come Intellij works well with JDK 10.0.2, while netbeans won't even open a new project? I tried to work with Netbeans, but it wouldn't open. However Intellij works very well.

Comment: What version of Netbeans? Netbeans 9.0 is for JDK>8

Answer (score 0):

Only NetBeans version 9.0 supports for Java version 9 and 10. Visit [**Apache NetBeans 9.0**](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/index.html) to know more and download.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Netbeans 8.2 or previous versions. As per [release note](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/82/relnotes.html#tech) it supports up to Java 8. Now Netbeans is governed by the [Apache Software Foundation](https://www.apache.org/). It is renamed as [Apache Netbeans](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html) starting from version 9.0. You can download from the link [here](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html). It does support all the latest versions of Java including Java 11.